# Colorizing raster in QGIS 2.2 without using OSGeo4W command line?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

Total beginner in QGIS. Following this guide right now:

https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog585/node/695

At step 4 I created the simple txt file which I now need to use to colorize the raster (slope.tif) I created before.
Now it tells me to "open your OSGeo4W command line window" to execute some commands to do the colorizing. Where can I find this command window or a command line window for the GDAL Plugins? Do I have to install something separately? I wouldn´t mind to using command line windows.
Or is there a way to do what is done in the tutorial just by using standalone QGIS Installation 2.2 (on Win 7 64bit system)? Perhaps by using the properties menu of the raster file? If yes please give some tipps for steps 4 to 8 of the guide. I guess the rest will be no problem.

Comment: The Q&A format of GIS SE works best with one question per Question so a tip for deciding whether what you are asking is too broad is to see if your Question contains only one question mark.  If you have more than one question then research/ask each one separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to gis.stackexchange Taya. To me, it seems like the guide you linked is really over-complicating this issue. I'd recommend you to use the [QGIS user guide](http://docs.qgis.org) instead if you want to learn about QGIS.

Concerning the issue at hand: Just load the original tif file in QGIS and then go to **Layer Properties | Style** and there you will be able to create the color ramp you desire.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the OSGeo4W version you should have a OSGeo4W folder in your Windows start menu. Just go there and look for the OSGeo4W entry, which should be the command line. You can also try the MSYS Shell, which is a linux type command line with all the GDAL goodies.

[image: How to start the OSGeo4W command line]

Answer (score 1):

Found out how you can do it directly in QGIS by reading this guide in the Training Manual:

http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/terrain_analysis.html

You just have to use the Menu under "Raster" - "Analysis" - "DEM Terrain Models" and select the "Mode" "color relief" in the Dropdown Menu.  I thought you only had one the menus under "Raster" - "Terrain Analysis" for slope, hillshade and so on.

In the DEM Terrain Models-Dialogue it also shows the exact same code as used in the first guide in the box below "load into canvas when finished".

@underdark: I already tried the layer properties - style but didn´t yet achieve the look I want.

Thanks for both answers since I can´t yet vote up ;)

Also edited this question as solved.

Comment: You can actually check off an answer as correct, instead of inserting [solved] into the title. There is a little check mark beneath the up/down buttons on each answer. I think it's a little hidden or not obvious until you hover your mouse over it.

Comment: Ah, found it. I´ll have to accept an answer but was looking for a way to mark the question as solved while editing the original question.